# Managing "A Database Error Occurred" 1062 error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm a CodeIgniter newbie and I'm beginning to explore the CI functions, especially, in this case, the Form costruction. I've already read the documentation about this and I've searched on the web, but didn't find a solution.

The main problem is that, when I specify, for a field, that its value must be unique, if I enter a specific value, then all goes ok, but if I don't I catch a "A Database Error Occurred" 1062 error (Duplicate entry "text" for key "key"). I'm doing something in the wrong way.

Here I will explain my code. Before that, I've read that, in order to use the `id_unique[tablename.tablefield]` you have to set first a unique id for that specific field, and that's what I've done.

Could you better explain to me what's happening?

Here is the function in the model:

```
function save_users() {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ");
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("username","username","trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","password","trim|required|md5");
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("email","email","trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]");

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}

public function username_check($str) {

    if ($str != "admin") {

        $this->load->model("new_model");            

        $this->form_validation->set_message("username_check", "The %s field cannot have username Test ");
        $this->form_validation->set_message("is_unique[users.email]","Errore!");

        $this->new_model->save_users();

        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you need, but there's a few changes I would make to your code. 
For instance, the callback. I don't think you should be adding the user into the database, from the callback function.

This should be done once the form validation has passed.

I would change your controller, to this;

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->model('new_model');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username' 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email' 'Email Address', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');

  if (!$this->form_validation->run())
  {
    $this->load->view('myform');
  }
  else
  {
    // Now we add the entry to the database
    if ($this->new_model->save_user())
    {
      echo 'user added!';
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'error within model';
    }
  }
}


public function username_check($username)
{
  if ($username == 'admin')
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s cannot be "admin"');
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

What I've done is remove the database entry from the callback function, and moved this into the index function, and it will run once the form validation has passed.

Does this solve your problem?

Running the function now, will say "error within model", this is because your model isn't returning anything back to the controller. Modify your save_user function, to this;

```
function save_users()
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ");
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, just one question: Why do you say: if / else construct "if ($this->new_model->save_users())"? I'm sorry but is that doesn't mean "if the function is executed"? But where do you execute it? I'm a bit unfamiliar with OOP logic, i need to study more. The second one is that: ok, the logic is running, but in that if (i previuously talked about), if i run as is written above, the "error within model" is thrown, even if the query is doing the right thing (found? don't insert, not found, insert)

Comment: That doesn't mean if the function is executed, it means if the function returns true, or false. I will amend my answer, with a new model function.

Comment: Aaah ok...i've understood now. Thank you for your detailed explanation, never used this condition before

Comment: You're welcome. I've been using CI for a few years now, and I still read the user_guide whenever I have a problem. 9 times out of 10, it would be covered in there. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/